# Set scroll speed and have a show desktop keyboard command on Mint 16

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse

How can I change the scroll speed and have a show desktop keyboard command?

I cannot figure out these two things. I have looked around, but cannot find any definitive or working advice.

edit_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**

my props for my mouse:

```
me@me-mint ~/ $ xinput --list-props "USB Optical Mouse"
Device 'USB Optical Mouse':
    Device Enabled (128):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (130): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (265): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (266):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (267):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (268):    10.000000
    Device Product ID (247):    1121, 19812
    Device Node (248):  "/dev/input/event5"
    Evdev Axis Inversion (269): 0, 0
    Evdev Axes Swap (271):  0
    Axis Labels (272):  "Rel X" (138), "Rel Y" (139), "Rel Horiz Wheel" (264), "Rel Vert Wheel" (274)
    Button Labels (273):    "Button Left" (131), "Button Middle" (132), "Button Right" (133), "Button Wheel Up" (134), "Button Wheel Down" (135), "Button Horiz Wheel Left" (136), "Button Horiz Wheel Right" (137)
    Evdev Middle Button Emulation (252):    0
    Evdev Middle Button Timeout (253):  50
    Evdev Third Button Emulation (254): 0
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (255): 1000
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (256):  3
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (257):   20
    Evdev Wheel Emulation (258):    0
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (259):   0, 0, 4, 5
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (260):    10
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (261):    200
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (262): 4
    Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (263):  0
```

Comment: Are you using Gnome? Cinnamon? XFCE4? Mate? KDE?

Comment: Cinnamon, the default for mint 16

Answer (score 1):

The articles on [changing mouse acceleration in Debian](http://510x.se/notes/posts/Changing_mouse_acceleration_in_Debian_and_Linux_in_general/) and [adjusting scroll speed in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/259628) provides some input. The following is quoted from the latter:

> To change the mouse parameters :
>
> `xinput list` # to list the peripherals, note the good number!
>   `xinput list-props 9` #list parameters from peripheral number 9
>   `xinput set-prop 9 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' 3` # set the acceleration of peripheral 9 to value 3.

The "magic number" 9 in the second command is the one corresponding to your pointing device that you note from the output of the first command.

Regarding the other question, in GNOME desktop, the [keyboard shortcut](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/45) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> minimizes all the open windows and thereby, effectively displaying the Desktop. I found it to work with Xfce. You can try with Cinnamon and verify.

Comment: ctrl+alt+d doesn't work in Cinnamon. I'm not sure what setting to use to effect my scroll rate.. please see my edit

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem. If you have already resolved, maybe late commers find help.

if you haven't got dconf-editor installed, do

```
# sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

then, open dconf-editor (through shell or menu). Thereafter, you can find the key: (quickly, find: "show-desktop")

```
> org > cinammon > muffin > keybindings
```

On the right side of the screen there is this key: **show-desktop** change the value to (exactly with apos.)

```
['<Super>d']
```

Mine worked. Here is the screenshot, if it helps further:

[image: Screenshot, dconf-editor, keybindings, show-desktop]

PS: It will make "Windows Key" + D combination to show desktop.